# How to shorten CD/DVD spin down time?

Tags: windows-8, dvd, compact-disc, disk-drive

In Windows XP, a tool like "Nero DriveSpeed" was capable of modifying the amount of time a CD / DVD drive leaves a disk spinning before it halts it (it was also possible to modify the maximum spinning speed of that drive).

It worked for almost every drive. But it doesn't anymore in Windows 8 (I think it had no effect since Windows Vista anymore).

Currently my spin-down time is about 10 minutes which is pretty annoying, I hear a constant noise the whole time the disk isn't even needed anymore (nothing is accessing it). My only solution is it to take out the disk (even though I will need it again soon), since I cannot create an image of it due to copy protection.

How to change the spin / down time in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out too. From what I can tell, there used to be a registry key that could be modified to change the drive spindown time. This registry key doesn't exist in newer versions of Windows, that's why the Nero tool doesn't work anymore. I haven't been able to find an equivalent registry key by searching the registry (I searched all keys with 'DVD' and 'Spindown' in the name). It looks like you can no longer modify the spindown time in Windows.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the author's question.

Comment: Good point, Brian. The registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DVDNavigator\DriveSpindown" has really been removed or renamed, cannot locate it in Windows 10 any more
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388590(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The regkey above is a part of DirectShow / qdvd.dll which has been part of DirectX SDK until February 2005. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx